# Tasks Multi-language support

Tags: process-builder, tasks

We have created the appropriate custom labels to translate tasks comments, after the task is created the comments are not being shown 'translated' to the user's language. The tasks are being created through a process we created in Process Builder.
What else do we need to do in order to show tasks in the user's language? Should we use workflows instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom labels are used for translating the metadata, for ex: custom messages, labels of the fields etc.

It can not be used for the data stored in the fields.

[Check this link for more details.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_translate_edit.htm&type=0)

I also don't see any solution for modifying the data in apex code also. You should either ask your users to enter the comments in the correct language itself.